# Is it a good practice to put UICollectionView and UITableView inside a UIScrollView in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I've googled questions like "Put a table view/collection view inside a scroll view", but all of those questions are asking about how to solve some of the unexpected behaviors when doing so, not many are asking if it's a good practice.

I used to use `react-native` to develop mobile apps. They have this component called `FlatList`, sort of like `UITableView` in Swift. I once put a `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView` and implemented the unlimited scroll, however, there were many strange things that happened:

1. I haven't even scrolled to the bottom, but the `FlatList` keeps rendering more data, as if it has already reached the end, which caused memory leak after a while
2. When I tried to get the current scroll position and do some animation based on it, it always gave me the wrong scroll position
3. etc ...

I wrote the same thing in Swift, none of the issues listed above came up. However, I want to ask, **if there could be any potential problems when doing so?**

To help you understand why I would want to put a table view & collection view inside a scroll view, look at this pic (If you could suggest some other way to do the same thing without having table view/collection view inside a scroll view, that'd be great!)

[image]

**Update**

I put everything inside a scroll view because I want to disable the keyboard on drag when user is typing in text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableView and CollectionView inherit from ScrollView. So that behaviour you mention is already on those components.

The 'best' practice would be to have only 1 CollectionView (without ScrollView nor TableView) and create your own CollectionViewLayout so you can define different layout and scrolling for each of your sections, but that could get a bit too complex as you would have to implement those behaviours yourself.

Another approach would be to have a main CollectionView, with another CollectionView inside for each of your sections (1 for the photos, 1 for the 'add location', 'tag person', etc).